# Integrating an inverse quadratic function

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

$$\int \frac{1}{ax^2+bx+c} dx$$
where $a,b<0$ and $c>0$ and $b^2-4ac>0$.

First of all I completed the square:
\begin{align}
ax^2+bx+c&=a[(x+\frac{b}{2a})^2+\frac{4ac-b^2}{4a^2}]\\
&=a[(x+\frac{b}{2a})^2-(\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a})^2]
\end{align}
So then I have:
$$\frac{1}{a}\int \frac{1}{(x+\frac{b}{2a})^2-(\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a})^2} dx$$
I'm guessing I need to substitute something so the integral is of the form:
$$\int \frac{1}{y^2- k^2}dy$$
If anyone could help me integrate this it would be very helpful.

Comment: try partial fractions

Comment: Integrate what ?.

Answer (score 1):

As the discriminant is positive, there are two real roots. Then

$$\frac1{a(x-r)(x-s)}=\frac1{a(s-r)}\left(\frac1{x-s}-\frac1{x-r}\right)$$

has the antiderivative

$$\frac1{a(s-r)}\log\left|\frac{x-s}{x-r}\right|.$$

Caution: as there are two vertical asymptotes (at $r$ and $s$), the integration bounds may no straddle them.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

let $r_1$ and $r_2$ be the roots of $ax^2+bx+c=0$. Then in three different cases we can solve the integral.

**Case 1 : $r_1\ne r_2,r_1,r_2\in \Bbb R$**

In this cases the integral would become$$\int{1\over ax^2+bx+c}dx=\int{1\over a(x-r_1)(x-r_2)}={1\over a}\int {1\over (r_1-r_2)(x-r_1)}+{1\over (r_2-r_1)(x-r_1)}dx$$

**Case 2: $r_1=r_2=r$**

In this case we have$$\int{1\over ax^2+bx+c}dx=\int{1\over a(x-r)^2}dx$$

**Case 3: $r_1=r_2^*\notin\Bbb R$**

For this case suppose $r_1=\alpha+i\beta$ therefore$$\int{1\over ax^2+bx+c}dx={1\over a}\int{1\over (x+\alpha)^2+\beta^2}dx$$then a simple change in variable solves the problem (a little tricky!)...

Comment: It is said that we are in **Case 1**.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Simply do $y=x+\frac b{2a}$ and let $k=\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$. Then, up to a constant, your integral becomes $\int\frac{\mathrm dy}{y^2-k^2}$. Now, use the fact that$$\frac1{y^2-k^2}=\frac1{2k}\left(\frac1{y-k}-\frac1{y+k}\right).$$